# Disable background click on alert in ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, alert

I am using ionic to bulid mobile app for ios and android. In my app when any ionic alert shown and when I click on background than the background functionality working. I want this to be disabled.
My alert box code is:

```
var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Alert',
       template: 'Please fill all fields first.'
   })
   .then(function(res) {
        // some code
    });
```

This will show an alert box on mobile but when i click on background side than background functionality working and I want to stop this.

For example : I have a form with multiple fields. I clicked on submit button and alert message is shown. When I click on "ok" button of alert the background input box which is behind the "ok" button also triggered. So I want to prevent this.

I searched for this issue but didn't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

Place this option *backdropDismiss* inside your .create object and assign false to it

Comment: Why has this -1? It`s the correct solution: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#backdropdismiss

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

HTML

```
<html ng-app="mySuperApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Popups
    </title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="padding" ng-controller="PopupCtrl">

    <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="showAlert()">
      Alert
    </button>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {

   // An alert dialog
   $scope.showAlert = function() {
     var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Alert',
       template: 'Please fill all fields first.'
     });
     alertPopup.then(function(res) {
       console.log('something');
     });
   };
```